# Как отследить кол-во попыток отправки формы с сайта (post)?

Tags: php

На сайте установлена форма которая получает данные со стороннего API.

Как можно отследить количество отправок данных из этой формы одним посетителем за один сеанс, чтобы, например, после 3 отправки формы, предложить посетителю зарегистрироваться в сервисе, при этом запретить отправку формы до регистрации.

Желательно реально запретить отправку формы на несколько часов или минут для конкретного посетителя.

Comment: Создать таблицу, куда записывать, например, ip + дату и при каждом запросе смотреть сколько запросов ушло в этот день, если меньше 3 - отправлять, иначе что хотите делайте

Comment: Спасибо, интересная идея, возможно так и буду делать тогда.